# Where can I find Linq ThenInclude method?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, model-view-controller

I saw some LINQ code examples which contains **ThenInclude**. Where can I find such method? In external library or other namespace.

I want to use such method for get data for derived, but I cannot find such method or do you know other solution

```
        return _dbContext.Goals
            .Where(p => p.Owner.Id == userId)
            .Include(p => p.GoalExpectation)
                .ThenInclude<RangeGoalExpectation>(p => p.MinValue)
                .ThenInclude<RangeGoalExpectation>(p => p.MaxValue)
                .ThenInclude<SpecifiedGoalExpectation>(p => p.Value)
```

Comment: It's EF Core extension method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[ThenInclude](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entityframeworkqueryableextensions#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions_ThenInclude__3_Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_Query_IIncludableQueryable___0___1__System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_System_Func___1___2___) is part of Entity Framework Core (EF 7).